# How to add classpaths for unit tests in maven ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

I am using maven to make a simple application and writing unit tests for it. I am new to both using maven as well as writing unit tests with Junit.

My directory structure is as follows :-

The source code classes used in my project are in the directory : -

`project-name/src/main/java/com/somename/app/packagename`

Main file (which contains static main method) is in :-

`project-name/src/main/java/com/somename/app/App.java`

The default unit test provided by Maven is in :-

`project-name/src/test/java/com/somename/app/AppTest.java`

Now, I have added a unit test in the above directory (in which AppTest.java) is there and this unit test needs to access the classes defined in the "packagename" directory as described above.

If it were a simple commandline , I would have added the classpath to the directory when compiling and running the application.

How should I do the same in Maven ? Also, is there any alternative to adding the classpath directly in maven ?

Comment: i do not think that you need any classpath settings to run unit test cases in maven. If your project is in same structure you have defined, then maven will run the test cases every time you build your project(can be turned off using -options). Let me know if i am deviating from the question.

Comment: @ppuskar I was also expecting the same but , the problem is exactly as I have told above.

Comment: @ps06756 Your comments below show that there is information missing in the question. Please edit the question to include the missing information.

Answer (score 3):

When using the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (which I always recommend as Maven is all about conventions), the following directories are always part of the classpath when running the tests:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

So there is no need to manually adjust anything for running the tests. The `mvn test` command simply does what you want.

Comment: Sir, I also expected the same, but the error is still coming, when I try to import the relevant packages in the src/main/java It is giving me the compiler error that the package does not exist.

Comment: can you please give some more detail... if the packages are in the correct location just try right clicking the project->maven->update project. it will update your project and may be it will help you

Comment: @ObuliSundar I am building my project from terminal

Comment: Ok, so I have a zephyr folder inside the usual app folder, which contains all other classes. Now, maven is not having problem while importing com.somename.app.* while if I import com.somename.app.zephyr.* It is saying that the required package does not exist.

Comment: @ps06756 "[...] but the error is still coming [...]" _What error?_ You didn't describe any error in your question. And please, don't put additional information into comments, but edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Ok, finally resolved the error by writing full package name in the relevant files, for the edit part I'll keep that in mind from next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Directory structure is always added in the class path. if you are using eclipse just got to Run as->maven build.(make sure you  have maven plugin installed) otherwise you can directly use the mvn clean , mvn install  command for building the project in maven.